# Office 365 API for Skype

Tags: azure, office365

According to the Office 365 API there is no Support yet for Skype for Bussiness, is that true? Link attach https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-managment-apis-overview

Can you please tell me how to access it in case it is available?

I have access to:

`•         O365 Tennant
•         Azure AD
•         Sharepoint online
•         Onedrive
•         Exchange online`

Thx

Jo